# rosserial arduino hello world won't verify

Tags: arduino, ros, arduino-ide

Edit: Solved

SOLUTION:

I'm running Arduino 1.0.5

I fixed the problem by changing /Sketchbook/library/ros_lib/ros/node_handle.h line 260 from

```
}else if (topic_ == TopicInfo::ID_TX_STOP){
```

to

```
}else if (topic_ == ID_TX_STOP){
```

However, this gave me a new error message:

```
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.cpp: In member function 'size_t Print::print(const __FlashStringHelper*)':
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.cpp:44:9: error: 'prog_char' does not name a type
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.cpp:47:23: error: 'p' was not declared in this scope
```

So to fix this I edited usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.cpp, line 44 from

```
const prog_char *p = (const prog_char *)ifsh;
```

to

```
const char PROGMEM *p = (const char PROGMEM *)ifsh;
```

Now it compiles!

Original Problem:

I've been using this tutorial to get everything set up: (http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup) I can install everything without an issue I think, the ros_lib folder is placed in my sketchbook libraries. But when I do the next tutorial with the helloworld example, the code does not verify correctly. When I try to verify with the checkmark in the Arduino IDE, I get the following set of error codes:

```
In file included from /home/user/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ros.h:38:0,
from HelloWorld.cpp:6:
/home/user/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ros/node_handle.h: In member function 'virtual int ros::NodeHandle_::spinOnce()':
/home/user/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ros/node_handle.h:260:45: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
/home/user/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ros/node_handle.h:260:45: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
```

I've reinstalled the ros_lib as well as rosserial and I keep getting this error, so I don't know what the problem is. I looked around line 260 of the node_handle.h file but I didn't notice anything out of place.

Here's node_handle.h: (spacing might be a little off)

```
/*
* Software License Agreement (BSD License)
*
* Copyright (c) 2011, Willow Garage, Inc.
* All rights reserved.
*
* Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
* modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
* are met:
*
*  * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
*    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
*  * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above
*    copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following
*    disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided
*    with the distribution.
*  * Neither the name of Willow Garage, Inc. nor the names of its
*    contributors may be used to endorse or promote prducts derived
*    from this software without specific prior written permission.
*
* THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
* "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
* LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS
* FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
* COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
* INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING,
* BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
* LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
* CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
* LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN
* ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
* POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
*/

#ifndef ROS_NODE_HANDLE_H_
#define ROS_NODE_HANDLE_H_

#include "std_msgs/Time.h"
#include "rosserial_msgs/TopicInfo.h"
#include "rosserial_msgs/Log.h"
#include "rosserial_msgs/RequestParam.h"

#define SYNC_SECONDS        5

#define MODE_FIRST_FF       0
/*
 * The second sync byte is a protocol version. It's value is 0xff for the first
 * version of the rosserial protocol (used up to hydro), 0xfe for the second version
 * (introduced in hydro), 0xfd for the next, and so on. Its purpose is to enable
 * detection of mismatched protocol versions (e.g. hydro rosserial_python with groovy
 * rosserial_arduino. It must be changed in both this file and in
 * rosserial_python/src/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py
 */
#define MODE_PROTOCOL_VER   1
#define PROTOCOL_VER1       0xff // through groovy
#define PROTOCOL_VER2       0xfe // in hydro
#define PROTOCOL_VER        PROTOCOL_VER2
#define MODE_SIZE_L         2   
#define MODE_SIZE_H         3
#define MODE_SIZE_CHECKSUM  4   // checksum for msg size received from size L and H
#define MODE_TOPIC_L        5   // waiting for topic id
#define MODE_TOPIC_H        6
#define MODE_MESSAGE        7
#define MODE_MSG_CHECKSUM   8   // checksum for msg and topic id 


#define MSG_TIMEOUT 20  //20 milliseconds to recieve all of message data

#define ID_TX_STOP 11  //hardcode for hydro version

#include "msg.h"

namespace ros {

  class NodeHandleBase_{
    public:
      virtual int publish(int id, const Msg* msg)=0;
      virtual int spinOnce()=0;
      virtual bool connected()=0;
    };
}

#include "publisher.h"
#include "subscriber.h"
#include "service_server.h"
#include "service_client.h"

namespace ros {

  using rosserial_msgs::TopicInfo;

  /* Node Handle */
  template<class Hardware,
       int MAX_SUBSCRIBERS=25,
       int MAX_PUBLISHERS=25,
       int INPUT_SIZE=512,
       int OUTPUT_SIZE=512>
  class NodeHandle_ : public NodeHandleBase_
  {
    protected:
      Hardware hardware_;

  /* time used for syncing */
  unsigned long rt_time;

  /* used for computing current time */
  unsigned long sec_offset, nsec_offset;

  unsigned char message_in[INPUT_SIZE];
  unsigned char message_out[OUTPUT_SIZE];

  Publisher * publishers[MAX_PUBLISHERS];
  Subscriber_ * subscribers[MAX_SUBSCRIBERS];

  /*
   * Setup Functions
   */
public:
  NodeHandle_() : configured_(false) {

    for(unsigned int i=0; i< MAX_PUBLISHERS; i++) 
   publishers[i] = 0;

    for(unsigned int i=0; i< MAX_SUBSCRIBERS; i++) 
   subscribers[i] = 0;

    for(unsigned int i=0; i< INPUT_SIZE; i++) 
   message_in[i] = 0;

    for(unsigned int i=0; i< OUTPUT_SIZE; i++) 
   message_out[i] = 0;

    req_param_resp.ints_length = 0;
    req_param_resp.ints = NULL;
    req_param_resp.floats_length = 0;
    req_param_resp.floats = NULL;
    req_param_resp.ints_length = 0;
    req_param_resp.ints = NULL;
  }

  Hardware* getHardware(){
    return &hardware_;
  }

  /* Start serial, initialize buffers */
  void initNode(){
    hardware_.init();
    mode_ = 0;
    bytes_ = 0;
    index_ = 0;
    topic_ = 0;
  };

  /* Start a named port, which may be network server IP, initialize buffers */
  void initNode(char *portName){
    hardware_.init(portName);
    mode_ = 0;
    bytes_ = 0;
    index_ = 0;
    topic_ = 0;
  };

protected:
  //State machine variables for spinOnce
  int mode_;
  int bytes_;
  int topic_;
  int index_;
  int checksum_;

  bool configured_;

  /* used for syncing the time */
  unsigned long last_sync_time;
  unsigned long last_sync_receive_time;
  unsigned long last_msg_timeout_time;

public:
  /* This function goes in your loop() function, it handles
   *  serial input and callbacks for subscribers.
   */


  virtual int spinOnce(){

    /* restart if timed out */
    unsigned long c_time = hardware_.time();
    if( (c_time - last_sync_receive_time) > (SYNC_SECONDS*2200) ){
        configured_ = false;
     }

    /* reset if message has timed out */
    if ( mode_ != MODE_FIRST_FF){ 
      if (c_time > last_msg_timeout_time){
        mode_ = MODE_FIRST_FF;
      }
    }

    /* while available buffer, read data */
    while( true )
    {
      int data = hardware_.read();
      if( data < 0 )
        break;
      checksum_ += data;
      if( mode_ == MODE_MESSAGE ){        /* message data being recieved */
        message_in[index_++] = data;
        bytes_--;
        if(bytes_ == 0)                  /* is message complete? if so, checksum */
          mode_ = MODE_MSG_CHECKSUM;
      }else if( mode_ == MODE_FIRST_FF ){
        if(data == 0xff){
          mode_++;
          last_msg_timeout_time = c_time + MSG_TIMEOUT;
        }
      }else if( mode_ == MODE_PROTOCOL_VER ){
        if(data == PROTOCOL_VER){
          mode_++;
        }else{
          mode_ = MODE_FIRST_FF;
          if (configured_ == false)
              requestSyncTime();    /* send a msg back showing our protocol version */
        }
  }else if( mode_ == MODE_SIZE_L ){   /* bottom half of message size */
        bytes_ = data;
        index_ = 0;
        mode_++;
        checksum_ = data;               /* first byte for calculating size checksum */
      }else if( mode_ == MODE_SIZE_H ){   /* top half of message size */
        bytes_ += data<<8;
    mode_++;
      }else if( mode_ == MODE_SIZE_CHECKSUM ){  
        if( (checksum_%256) == 255)
      mode_++;
    else 
      mode_ = MODE_FIRST_FF;          /* Abandon the frame if the msg len is wrong */
  }else if( mode_ == MODE_TOPIC_L ){  /* bottom half of topic id */
        topic_ = data;
        mode_++;
        checksum_ = data;               /* first byte included in checksum */
      }else if( mode_ == MODE_TOPIC_H ){  /* top half of topic id */
        topic_ += data<<8;
        mode_ = MODE_MESSAGE;
        if(bytes_ == 0)
          mode_ = MODE_MSG_CHECKSUM;  
      }else if( mode_ == MODE_MSG_CHECKSUM ){ /* do checksum */
        mode_ = MODE_FIRST_FF;
        if( (checksum_%256) == 255){
          if(topic_ == TopicInfo::ID_PUBLISHER){
            requestSyncTime();
            negotiateTopics();
            last_sync_time = c_time;
            last_sync_receive_time = c_time;
            return -1;
          }else if(topic_ == TopicInfo::ID_TIME){
            syncTime(message_in);
          }else if (topic_ == TopicInfo::ID_PARAMETER_REQUEST){
              req_param_resp.deserialize(message_in);
              param_recieved= true;
          }else if(topic_ == TopicInfo::ID_TX_STOP){
              configured_ = false;
          }else{
            if(subscribers[topic_-100])
              subscribers[topic_-100]->callback( message_in );
          }
        }
      }
    }

    /* occasionally sync time */
    if( configured_ && ((c_time-last_sync_time) > (SYNC_SECONDS*500) )){
      requestSyncTime();
      last_sync_time = c_time;
    }

    return 0;
  }


  /* Are we connected to the PC? */
  virtual bool connected() {
    return configured_;
  };

  /********************************************************************
   * Time functions
   */

  void requestSyncTime()
  {
    std_msgs::Time t;
    publish(TopicInfo::ID_TIME, &t);
    rt_time = hardware_.time();
  }

  void syncTime( unsigned char * data )
  {
    std_msgs::Time t;
    unsigned long offset = hardware_.time() - rt_time;

    t.deserialize(data);
    t.data.sec += offset/1000;
    t.data.nsec += (offset%1000)*1000000UL;

    this->setNow(t.data);
    last_sync_receive_time = hardware_.time();
  }

  Time now(){
    unsigned long ms = hardware_.time();
    Time current_time;
    current_time.sec = ms/1000 + sec_offset;
    current_time.nsec = (ms%1000)*1000000UL + nsec_offset;
    normalizeSecNSec(current_time.sec, current_time.nsec);
    return current_time;
  }

  void setNow( Time & new_now )
  {
    unsigned long ms = hardware_.time();
    sec_offset = new_now.sec - ms/1000 - 1;
    nsec_offset = new_now.nsec - (ms%1000)*1000000UL + 1000000000UL;
    normalizeSecNSec(sec_offset, nsec_offset);
  }

  /********************************************************************
   * Topic Management 
   */

  /* Register a new publisher */    
  bool advertise(Publisher & p)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_PUBLISHERS; i++){
      if(publishers[i] == 0){ // empty slot
        publishers[i] = &p;
        p.id_ = i+100+MAX_SUBSCRIBERS;
        p.nh_ = this;
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  /* Register a new subscriber */
  template<typename MsgT>
  bool subscribe(Subscriber< MsgT> & s){
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SUBSCRIBERS; i++){
      if(subscribers[i] == 0){ // empty slot
        subscribers[i] = (Subscriber_*) &s;
        s.id_ = i+100;
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  /* Register a new Service Server */
  template<typename MReq, typename MRes>
  bool advertiseService(ServiceServer<MReq,MRes>& srv){
    bool v = advertise(srv.pub);
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SUBSCRIBERS; i++){
      if(subscribers[i] == 0){ // empty slot
        subscribers[i] = (Subscriber_*) &srv;
        srv.id_ = i+100;
        return v;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  /* Register a new Service Client */
  template<typename MReq, typename MRes>
  bool serviceClient(ServiceClient<MReq, MRes>& srv){
    bool v = advertise(srv.pub);
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SUBSCRIBERS; i++){
      if(subscribers[i] == 0){ // empty slot
        subscribers[i] = (Subscriber_*) &srv;
        srv.id_ = i+100;
        return v;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  void negotiateTopics()
  {
    rosserial_msgs::TopicInfo ti;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_PUBLISHERS; i++)
    {
      if(publishers[i] != 0) // non-empty slot
      {
        ti.topic_id = publishers[i]->id_;
        ti.topic_name = (char *) publishers[i]->topic_;
        ti.message_type = (char *) publishers[i]->msg_->getType();
        ti.md5sum = (char *) publishers[i]->msg_->getMD5();
        ti.buffer_size = OUTPUT_SIZE;
        publish( publishers[i]->getEndpointType(), &ti );
      }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_SUBSCRIBERS; i++)
    {
      if(subscribers[i] != 0) // non-empty slot
      {
        ti.topic_id = subscribers[i]->id_;
        ti.topic_name = (char *) subscribers[i]->topic_;
        ti.message_type = (char *) subscribers[i]->getMsgType();
        ti.md5sum = (char *) subscribers[i]->getMsgMD5();
        ti.buffer_size = INPUT_SIZE;
        publish( subscribers[i]->getEndpointType(), &ti );
      }
    }
    configured_ = true;
  }

  virtual int publish(int id, const Msg * msg)
  {
    if(id >= 100 && !configured_) 
  return 0;

    /* serialize message */
    unsigned int l = msg->serialize(message_out+7);

    /* setup the header */
    message_out[0] = 0xff;
    message_out[1] = PROTOCOL_VER;
    message_out[2] = (unsigned char) ((unsigned int)l&255);
    message_out[3] = (unsigned char) ((unsigned int)l>>8);
message_out[4] = 255 - ((message_out[2] + message_out[3])%256);
    message_out[5] = (unsigned char) ((int)id&255);
    message_out[6] = (unsigned char) ((int)id>>8);

    /* calculate checksum */
    int chk = 0;
    for(int i =5; i<l+7; i++)
      chk += message_out[i];
    l += 7;
    message_out[l++] = 255 - (chk%256);

    if( l <= OUTPUT_SIZE ){
      hardware_.write(message_out, l);
      return l;
    }else{
      logerror("Message from device dropped: message larger than buffer.");
      return -1;
    }
  }

  /********************************************************************
   * Logging
   */

private:
  void log(char byte, const char * msg){
    rosserial_msgs::Log l;
    l.level= byte;
    l.msg = (char*)msg;
    publish(rosserial_msgs::TopicInfo::ID_LOG, &l);
  }

public:
  void logdebug(const char* msg){
    log(rosserial_msgs::Log::ROSDEBUG, msg);
  }
  void loginfo(const char * msg){
    log(rosserial_msgs::Log::INFO, msg);
  }
  void logwarn(const char *msg){
    log(rosserial_msgs::Log::WARN, msg);
  }
  void logerror(const char*msg){
    log(rosserial_msgs::Log::ERROR, msg);
  }
  void logfatal(const char*msg){
    log(rosserial_msgs::Log::FATAL, msg);
  }

  /********************************************************************
   * Parameters
   */

private:
  bool param_recieved;
  rosserial_msgs::RequestParamResponse req_param_resp;

  bool requestParam(const char * name, int time_out =  1000){
    param_recieved = false;
    rosserial_msgs::RequestParamRequest req;
    req.name  = (char*)name;
    publish(TopicInfo::ID_PARAMETER_REQUEST, &req);
    unsigned int end_time = hardware_.time() + time_out;
    while(!param_recieved ){
      spinOnce();
      if (hardware_.time() > end_time) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

public:
  bool getParam(const char* name, int* param, int length =1){
    if (requestParam(name) ){
      if (length == req_param_resp.ints_length){
        //copy it over
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
          param[i] = req_param_resp.ints[i];
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  bool getParam(const char* name, float* param, int length=1){
    if (requestParam(name) ){
      if (length == req_param_resp.floats_length){
        //copy it over
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++) 
          param[i] = req_param_resp.floats[i];
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  bool getParam(const char* name, char** param, int length=1){
    if (requestParam(name) ){
      if (length == req_param_resp.strings_length){
        //copy it over
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
          strcpy(param[i],req_param_resp.strings[i]);
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }  
  };

}

#endif
```

I tried commenting out line 160 and 161:

```
          //}else if (topic_ == TopicInfo::ID_TX_STOP){
              //configured_ = false;
```

This gave me a different error message:

```
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.cpp: In member function 'size_t Print::print(const __FlashStringHelper*)':
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.cpp:44:9: error: 'prog_char' does not name a type
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.cpp:47:23: error: 'p' was not declared in this scope
```

So here's Print.cpp

```
/*
 Print.cpp - Base class that provides print() and println()
 Copyright (c) 2008 David A. Mellis.  All right reserved.

 This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
 License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
 version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

 This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
 Lesser General Public License for more details.

 You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
 License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
 Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA

 Modified 23 November 2006 by David A. Mellis
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "Arduino.h"

#include "Print.h"

// Public Methods //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* default implementation: may be overridden */
size_t Print::write(const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size)
{
  size_t n = 0;
  while (size--) {
    n += write(*buffer++);
  }
  return n;
}

size_t Print::print(const __FlashStringHelper *ifsh)
{
  const prog_char *p = (const prog_char *)ifsh;
  size_t n = 0;
  while (1) {
    unsigned char c = pgm_read_byte(p++);
    if (c == 0) break;
    n += write(c);
  }
  return n;
}

size_t Print::print(const String &s)
{
  size_t n = 0;
  for (uint16_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    n += write(s[i]);
  }
  return n;
}

size_t Print::print(const char str[])
{
  return write(str);
}

size_t Print::print(char c)
{
  return write(c);
}

size_t Print::print(unsigned char b, int base)
{
  return print((unsigned long) b, base);
}

size_t Print::print(int n, int base)
{
  return print((long) n, base);
}

size_t Print::print(unsigned int n, int base)
{
  return print((unsigned long) n, base);
}

size_t Print::print(long n, int base)
{
  if (base == 0) {
    return write(n);
  } else if (base == 10) {
    if (n < 0) {
      int t = print('-');
      n = -n;
      return printNumber(n, 10) + t;
    }
    return printNumber(n, 10);
  } else {
    return printNumber(n, base);
  }
}

size_t Print::print(unsigned long n, int base)
{
  if (base == 0) return write(n);
  else return printNumber(n, base);
}

size_t Print::print(double n, int digits)
{
  return printFloat(n, digits);
}

size_t Print::println(const __FlashStringHelper *ifsh)
{
  size_t n = print(ifsh);
  n += println();
  return n;
}

size_t Print::print(const Printable& x)
{
  return x.printTo(*this);
}

size_t Print::println(void)
{
  size_t n = print('\r');
  n += print('\n');
  return n;
}

size_t Print::println(const String &s)
{
  size_t n = print(s);
  n += println();
  return n;
}

size_t Print::println(const char c[])
{
  size_t n = print(c);
  n += println();
  return n;
}

size_t Print::println(char c)
{
  size_t n = print(c);
  n += println();
  return n;
}

size_t Print::println(unsigned char b, int base)
{
  size_t n = print(b, base);
  n += println();
  return n;
}

size_t Print::println(int num, int base)
{
  size_t n = print(num, base);
  n += println();
  return n;
}

size_t Print::println(unsigned int num, int base)
{
  size_t n = print(num, base);
  n += println();
  return n;
}

size_t Print::println(long num, int base)
{
  size_t n = print(num, base);
  n += println();
  return n;
}

size_t Print::println(unsigned long num, int base)
{
  size_t n = print(num, base);
  n += println();
  return n;
}

size_t Print::println(double num, int digits)
{
  size_t n = print(num, digits);
  n += println();
  return n;
}

size_t Print::println(const Printable& x)
{
  size_t n = print(x);
  n += println();
  return n;
}

// Private Methods /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

size_t Print::printNumber(unsigned long n, uint8_t base) {
  char buf[8 * sizeof(long) + 1]; // Assumes 8-bit chars plus zero byte.
  char *str = &buf[sizeof(buf) - 1];

  *str = '\0';

  // prevent crash if called with base == 1
  if (base < 2) base = 10;

  do {
    unsigned long m = n;
    n /= base;
    char c = m - base * n;
    *--str = c < 10 ? c + '0' : c + 'A' - 10;
  } while(n);

  return write(str);
}

size_t Print::printFloat(double number, uint8_t digits) 
{ 
  size_t n = 0;

  // Handle negative numbers
  if (number < 0.0)
  {
     n += print('-');
     number = -number;
  }

  // Round correctly so that print(1.999, 2) prints as "2.00"
  double rounding = 0.5;
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<digits; ++i)
    rounding /= 10.0;

  number += rounding;

  // Extract the integer part of the number and print it
  unsigned long int_part = (unsigned long)number;
  double remainder = number - (double)int_part;
  n += print(int_part);

  // Print the decimal point, but only if there are digits beyond
  if (digits > 0) {
    n += print("."); 
  }

  // Extract digits from the remainder one at a time
  while (digits-- > 0)
  {
    remainder *= 10.0;
    int toPrint = int(remainder);
    n += print(toPrint);
    remainder -= toPrint; 
  } 

  return n;
}
```